# ASP.NET - Calculate Math Expression from Textbox

Tags: asp.net, math, calculator

I'm developing ASP.NET application and I need to calculate maths expressions like

```
16+25*(15.38-12.16)
```

which is entered in a text box control and to get result in other text box or label or wherever.

I tried some of these, but not of much help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equation+c%23

Is there a possible way to do it?

Comment: Of course there is a possible way to do this. What have you done?  Where are you having problems at?  What part are you looking for help on or are you looking for someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use [`DataTable.Compute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) but it can only handle simple equations.
This should work:

C#

```
private double CalcEquation(string equation)
{
    DataTable tempTable = new DataTable();

    var result =  tempTable.Compute(equation, "");
}
```

VB.Net

```
Private Sub CalcEquation(ByVal equation As String)

    Dim tempTable As New DataTable()

    Dim result As Object = tempTable.Compute(equation, "")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com) library.  It can handle more complex functions.

```
using System;
using NCalc;
namespace NCalcExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string evalString = "sin(2.0)+3";
            Expression e = new Expression(evalString, EvaluateOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Evaluate());
        }
    }
}
```